# Indeterminate expression. Where?

Tags: warning-messages, summation

Consider the following:

```
a[m_, n_, x_] := 
    1/2^n (-1)^n/((2 n)!) Sum[Binomial[m, l] (m - 2 l)^(2 n), {l, 0, m}] x^(2 n)

a[m_, 0, x_] := 1

f[m_, x_] := Sum[a[m, n, x], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Indeterminate expression]

I'm totally clueless why Mathematica fills in $0$ for $x$ while I feed it $x = 1$!

Comment: Please also copy the code into the text editor so that we can more easily test your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you define `f[m_,x_]` by `Sum[a[m,n,x],{n,0,Infinity}]` so there are terms in the sum like `0^0` because :

```
a[0,n,1]=1/2^n ((-1)^n)/((2n)!) Sum[Binomial[0,l] (0-2l)^(2n),{l,0,0}] x^(2n)
```

When there is `a[0,n,1]` you start the sum with `Sum[Binomial[0,l] (0-2l)^(2n),{l,0,0}]` and the first term in the definition of `f[m_,x_]` is with `n==0`.

**Edit**

To prevent generating of messages one can define `a[m,n,x]` and `f[m,x]` this way :

```
a[m_Integer, n_Integer, x_] /; n > 0 := 
  1/2^n (-1)^n/((2 n)!) Sum[ Binomial[m, l] (m - 2l)^(2n), {l, 0, m}] x^(2 n)
a[m_Integer, 0, x_] := 1
f[m_Integer, x_] := Sum[ a[ m, n, x], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 9):

It is not because of `x`, but because the `Sum` in the definition of `a`.

```
In[12]:= Sum[Binomial[m, l] (m - 2 l)^(2 n), {l, 0, m}] /. m -> 0

Out[12]= 0^(2 n)
```